# Cluster hanging on node failure

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello all of you bright people,

We’re currently running a smallish 300 GB cluster in production on 5 nodes with around 30 mil docs. Everything works flawlessly except when a node really goes down (I mean like network or HW failure).

Generally when we lose a node the cluster becomes more or less completely unresponsive for a few minutes. Both regarding indexing and querying. This is of course, less than ideal as we have load 24/7.

I would really appreciate some help with understanding best practice settings to have robust cluster.

First goal for us is for the cluster to not become unresponsive in the event of a node crash. After reading everything I could find on the web I can't really understand if ES is designed to be unresponsive for ping_retries*ping_timeout seconds or if the cluster will continue to server query requests even during this time. Could anyone help me shed light on this?

Secondly in the event of a even worse failure where the cluster goes into red state, would it be possible to allow the cluster to still serve read/query requests?

I would be ever so grateful for anyone willing to help me understand how this works or what we would need to change to make our ES installation more robust.

I’ve included our config here:

```
cluster.name: clustername
node.name: nodename
path.data: /data
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.ping.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.enabled: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1","host2","host3"]
bootstrap.mlockall: true
http.cors.enabled: true
index.number_of_shards: 10
action.disable_delete_all_indices: true
marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: ["marvel:9200"]
```

Comment: How many replicas you have? Any network saturation when rebalancing happens? Any timeouts reported in logs?

Comment: 1 replica. No timouts in the logs.

Comment: How much heap, how much RAM on the machines, local deployment, cloud, what kind of storage (ssd, spinning, other), what ES version, how many shards per each node, any old GC in the logs, is the cluster queried and indexed into continously, how frequent the indexing and querying, at the time of the network failure are there any indexing or querying going on? Also, look at Marvel graphs to see if there are any spikes in them at the time of the network failure. If there are, where do you see them and what kind of spikes?

Comment: @AndreiStefan , thanks for responding. Before I start answering all of that could you perhaps start by shedding light on the design issue.  When ES looses a node (unexpectedly), is the system designed to be unresponsive ping_retries*ping_timeout seconds?

Comment: No, that shouldn't happen. But the problem here is that you didn't provide some details. For example, what node did you loose? (master, regular) Did the cluster went into yellow state? After some time, was it back to green (even if the node that went down was still down)? I imagine that after one went down, the cluster started re-balancing itself (moving shards around, promoting replicas to primaries, making new replicas). So, there are some things to look at. Also, after stopped being "unresponsive" did it serve there requests you sent to it while being unresponsive? (but later)

Comment: Thanks for your response. We lost the master. Its hard to know what state the cluster went into as it became totally unresponsive. After a 18 minutes it started to respond in yellow state and thereafter started the normal replication/rebalancing. During the unresponsive state the cluster did serve sporadic requests but the vast majority did not complete successfully.

Comment: Ok. This is what I believe happened: you lost the master, it took the default of 1.5 minutes for other nodes' pings to fail (3 times * 0.5 minutes timeout) and to make them elect a new master. The problem is not the waiting for pings, but why did the master fail. The most common reason is a long old GC, longer than 1.5 minutes. Or many old GC less than 1.5 minutes but significantly large. During this time, everything on the master node is frozen. This means that the shards it held were also not able to respond. So, everything related to that node was unresponsive.

Comment: Assuming the other nodes finally established the master went away, after some time. I'm saying some time because you could have had many longer old GCs and still some pings to succeed. And it could have been longer than 1.5 minutes. Let's say you had a 1 minute old GC and after 30 seconds another one and so on. In this case some pings would have succeeded and some not. Not enough to decide that the master went away. Now let's assume it went away: the other nodes elect a new master. Depending on how you had the shards distributed in the cluster, maybe the cluster went `red`.

Comment: Or maybe it went `yellow` from the start. Again, depending on the amount of data, shards started to be moved around, copies have been made from the replicas etc. This could take some time and corroborated with the operations you wanted to perform on the cluster these could have been put in the waiting queue, waiting for the administrative operations to finish. Now, another thing to look at: what did trigger the master to be unresponsive, was it long GC? If it was a long GC, did other nodes experience long old GCs? If so, it could be that you lost more than one nodes.

Comment: My advice is to check the log files from *all* the nodes and build a serie of events (who went down first and why, what happened afterwards, who became master etc).

Comment: The master died because of a kernel panic. Unrelated to ES.

Comment: Then I believe there are 1.5 minutes until the remaining nodes elect a new master. For the rest of the time you need to inspect the logs. I'm sorry, but this would be the only way to know what happened. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Cluster hangs on failure because of the `fault detection timeout` value:

```
discovery.zen.fd.ping_interval: 1s -> default 1s
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: 2s -> default 30 secs
discovery.zen.fd.ping_retries: 3 -> default 3 secs
```

There are two fault detection processes running.

**The first** is by the master, pings all the other nodes in the cluster and verify that they are alive.

**Second**, each node pings to master to verify if its still alive or an election process needs to be initiated.

With above Configuration: 
If a node fails, Master will retries 3 times with timeout of 2 seconds (sum=6secs hang) instead of 90s wait(hang).

Please note I'm running cluster on local network with <1ms and 1Gbps connectivity, Depending on your environment you should adjust accordingly.
I'm on elasticsearch 5.1.1, you should refer to your version documentation for exact syntax.